# Setting parameters in pyomo

Tags: python, parameter-passing, cplex, pyomo

I am using `CPLEX` with `pyomo`. I would like to set the parameter `mip.limits.solutions = 1`. How to do this with either `.options(` or `.set_options(` or any other way?

I have tried the following but nothing works:

```
   from pyomo.environ import *

   opt = SolverFactory("cplex")

   opt.set_options('miplimitssolutions=1')  # does not work
   opt.set_options('mip.limits.solutions=1')  # does not work

   opt.options['mip'] = 'limits'  # this works up to here but how to continue?
```

Answer (score 2):

Pyomo's (LP file-based) CPLEX interface passes options using CPLEX's "Interactive" API.  In this case, the interactive version of that option is "`mip limits solutions`":

```
from pyomo.environ import *
opt = SolverFactory("cplex")
opt.options['mip limits solutions'] = 1
```